# Java StackTrace returns line number that only has close bracket

Tags: java, stack-trace

I run a stacktrace on a java program, and it returns a line number that points to a line that only has a close bracket.  The thread that this code is in seems to be in a bad state, as there are no exceptions but the thread is consuming 98% or more of the CPU.  Whenever I see the CPU being hogged, or notice that the thread is in a bad state (events are not being processed), the stacktrace always points to the line shown below.  While I have seen this a couple of times, I cannot manually reproduce this problem.  Does anyone know what it means when the stacktrace points to a close bracket?

```
    ...
while (true) {
    try {
        event = eventBlockingQueue.take();
        ... process event ...
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ... log ...
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        ... log ...
    } <-- Stacktrace points here!
}
```

Comment: When I see this I'm usually looking at source that's not the same version as the binary.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it? It could be the case that the project didn't build properly for whatever reason, and the code you're looking at is not the code being run, hence the seemingly incorrect line number.

Comment: @BlakeHood good suggestion. If in eclipse: `Project>Clean`, then, if `Project>Build Automatically` is not selected, `Project>Build All`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the source code you are debugging is not the same as the bytecode (compiled code). I would try cleaning and rebuilding the project. If you're debugging a JAR, then make sure the source code you have matches the version of the JAR you have.

Comment: I double-checked that the code is the same as the binary I am running, and it is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the stack trace is on the close bracket because the JVM is cleaning up the stack memory that just became obviated (by the close bracket).